# What is the best approach to passing data from a notification to the application that it opens, using "react-native-firebase v6"?

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I want to implement opening a specific screen when interacting with a Push Notification sent from Firebase. My understanding is that I needed to use was `getInitialNotification()` function that was available in `react-native-firebase v5` and lower, but is not available yet in `react-native-firebase v6`, since the Notifications package is not yet ready. 
Among other things, so far I have tried setting the background message handler that is available in the Cloud Messaging package, but it doesn't seem to work for something that is not a `data-only` message:

`Firebase.messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
   await storeJSONData('notification', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
});`

Should I downgrade to `react-native-firebase v5` in order to use their `getInitialNotification()` from the Notifications package, or do I have other better alternatives, like even using android native code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this issue by using the `react-native-push-notification` package on top of the firebase cloud messaging and implementing the `onNotification` function from that one.

```
PushNotification.configure({
      onNotification: function(notification)
      {
        // process the notification
        console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification);
        //iOS only
        notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
      },
      permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true
      },
      popInitialNotification: true,
      requestPermissions: true,
});
```